# Windows firewall - stop all programs from accessing the internet with exceptions, ideally in powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-firewall, windows-server-2019

I'd like to use Windows Firewall outgoing rules to block all programs from accessing the internet except the following:

- c:\zx\CertifyTheWeb - an app which refreshes IIS certificates
- World Wide Web - if our web app contains a httpget/httppost or web api integration I want that to work
- c:\zx\BatchProcessor - one more app which we want to have internet access

I'd like to create one or more rules to do this using powershell, but even just knowing how to do it in any language or manually would help.

I can see that I can allow svchost.exe, but I don't want other services which use that accessing the internet, only world wide web.

This would also block windows updates, which is also desirable in this case.

I don't really mind if this can be done with one rule, or if it needs 3 rules. Either is fine :)

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far and where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: I am stuck on how to restrict svchost to only allow one service when svchost is used by many services. I am presently trying to write a script to do this and test it.

Comment: I can see netsh has a -service parameter, but what to put in there? W3SVC ? or IISSVCS ?

Comment: Also it's difficult to test whether other services are blocked, so I think I do need someone to help me to "get it right first time"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a powershell script which does all of what I asked. Use with care as it does initially delete all firewall rules, which may cause momentary connectivity issues if you have live applications running on that server.

```
$RDPPORT = 39123

"DELETE ALL RULES"
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule all

"LOCKDOWN OUTGOING PORTS"
netsh advfirewall set allprofiles firewallpolicy blockinbound,blockoutbound

# dns is needed for internet to work
"DNS"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Core Networking (DNS-Out)" dir=out action=allow protocol=UDP remoteport=53 program="c:\windows\system32\svchost.exe" service="dnscache"

"RDP $RDPPORT"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Remote Desktop (TCP-In) $RDPPORT" dir=in localport=$RDPPORT protocol=tcp action=allow
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Remote Desktop (UDP-In) $RDPPORT" dir=in localport=$RDPPORT protocol=udp action=allow

"IN 443"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Core Networking (HTTPS-In)" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=443 remoteport=any

"Certify The Web 80"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Core Networking (HTTP-Out) c1" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP remoteport=80 program="C:\Program Files\CertifyTheWeb\Certify.exe"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Core Networking (HTTP-Out) c2" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP remoteport=80 program="C:\Program Files\CertifyTheWeb\CertifySSLManager.Service.exe"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Core Networking (HTTP-Out) c3" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP remoteport=80 program="C:\Program Files\CertifyTheWeb\Certify.UI.exe"

"Certify The Web 443"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Core Networking (HTTPS-Out) c1" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP remoteport=443 program="C:\Program Files\CertifyTheWeb\Certify.exe"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Core Networking (HTTPS-Out) c2" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP remoteport=443 program="C:\Program Files\CertifyTheWeb\CertifySSLManager.Service.exe"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Core Networking (HTTPS-Out) c3" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP remoteport=443 program="C:\Program Files\CertifyTheWeb\Certify.UI.exe"

"W3SVC 443"
#netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Core Networking (HTTPS-Out) IIS1" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP remoteport=443 program="%%systemroot%%\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe"
"W3SVC 443"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Core Networking (HTTPS-Out) IIS1" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP remoteport=443 service="W3SVC"
"443 Out - KEEP THIS RULE DISABLED"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="443 Out - KEEP THIS RULE DISABLED" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP remoteport=443

"BATCH 443"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Core Networking (HTTPS-Out) Batch" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP remoteport=443 program="C:\Program Files\MyApp\Web Server\Database Administrator\MyAppBatchService7.exe"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="FTP Outbound Batch" dir=out action=allow remoteip=any localip=any protocol=TCP localport=any remoteport=20,21,990,989,10000-10125,57000-60000 profile=any

"BATCH SMTP 25"
# netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Core Networking (SMTP-Out) Batch" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP remoteport=25 program="C:\Program Files\MyApp\Web Server\Database Administrator\MyAppBatchService7.exe"
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Core Networking (SMTP-Out) Batch" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP remoteport=25

netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state ON
```